# error: function definition is not allowed here in xeus-cling

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook, xeus-cling

I recently installed `xeus-cling` using below command,

```sh
conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge
```

It is working fine for other function but for below function I am getting error,

```cpp
pair<int,int> max_min_array(int *arr, int n) {
  int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    if(arr[i] < min) 
      min = arr[i];
    else if(arr[i] > max) 
      max = arr[i];
  }
  return make_pair(min,max);
}
```

### error

```
input_line_9:2:47: error: function definition is not allowed here
 pair<int,int> max_min_array(int *arr, int n) {
                                              ^

Interpreter Error:
```

Before that function cell, I have another cell where I am importing

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
```

### My Observation

below function works fine,

```cpp
int max_min_array(int *arr, int n) {
  int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    if(arr[i] < min) 
      min = arr[i];
    else if(arr[i] > max) 
      max = arr[i];
  }
  return min;
}
```

Comment: This usually means you're missing one or more closing curly brackets (`}`) in the function that is right before this one.

Comment: I am not missing anything. I checked number of times

Comment: I'm running into same problem (different function). Xeus-cling works fine for some f() but not others. Also seems xeus-cling remembers that it is using some namespaces from previous code cells, but not others. These glitches are without pattern?

Comment: I'm still getting familiar with xeus-cling so I could be mistaken, but I believe I'm beginning to see a pattern: If you define a function in the top-level scope of a cell, that's the only thing that can go in that cell. Ran into this with using statements and some variable definitions outside the function definition once; after moving them inside the function all my troubles went away.